# Is my AD password sent in plain text then encrypted?

Tags: authentication, passwords, active-directory

how does an application authenticate with AD credentials? Are the credentials sent in plain text? or are they encrypted before it checks with AD to validate the user?

Comment: How do you think anyone is supposed to know what application you use at work and how does that application work?

Comment: @techraf  I'll edit my question

Comment: You still haven't provided sufficient information.  But the answer is 'maybe'.

Comment: How can the answer be "maybe" - I don't think that the service that protects many of the worlds largest and sensitive server farms would allow plain text passwords to be transmitted? True, you might be able to *send* in clear text from a stupid app but AD wouldn't do anything with it as it needs an encrypted password.

Comment: @user6934502: How is that app created? Is it a bespoke application? One purchased off-the-shelf? Or are you simply referring to how a computer logs in? More info please.

Comment: @JulianKnight I was just wondering in general. Let's say I have MS Active Directory and I authenticate to our time card application with active directoy. When I type my password it shows as ........  but I was wondering how does the application authenticate with active directory? Does it send it plain text then compare? does it use the same encryption algorithm as AD? The time card application is web based and uses https if that matters.

Comment: Ok. Yes, that matters.  If it uses https, than nothing is sent in clear text - it is sent encrypted.  If is uses http, things may be going plain text (it would be up to the application to appropriately encrypt)

Comment: @crovers: Potentially 2 things being conflated there. HTTPS may have little to do with AD authentication, it is only really a transport not the data.

Comment: @user6934502: There are many ways to achieve what you describe. Typically, the app will hand-off authentication to AD using a standard such as OAuth for web apps, more likely SAML for on-prem traditional applications. In all of those cases, nothing will happen in the clear. Just to say that the services providing the authentication will be closely tied to the AD, typically running on Windows servers which will be signed into the domain - the servers use yet another different authentication, one more suited for local networks.

Comment: @JulianKnight Right - I was referring to the passage from client to server, not beyond.

Comment: AD uses Kerberos/GSSAPI. You could (stupidly) configure it to send in plain text, but that is not the default

Answer (score 0):

For a web app, what typically happens is that the app will use a standard-based authentication service such as OAuth or SAML. The app will hand-off authentication to an authentication server that runs "close" to the AD server. The authentication server is likely to be something running on a Windows server logged into the "Domain" provided by AD.

```
User -> Login page -> Internet -> Firewall -> 
          Web app server -> Firewall -> 
               Authentication Server -> Windows domain
```

Of course, that isn't the only way of doing it, there are dozens of different architectures and applications to achieve the same thing. That's why we've been asking for further information about the apps.

Microsoft have the "[Web Application Proxy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584113%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)" for example that will do this. It, in turn, uses [Active Directory Federation Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn383640(v=ws.11).aspx) to link to the domain.